# How to get cell column value from datagridview

Tags: vb.net

How to get cell column value from datagridview and if it is equal to OVERDUE, the back cell color will change.

```
----------------------------------
id     |   uname    |  lname     |
---------------------------------
1      |   anne|    |    a       |
----------------------------------
2      |   rays     |    b       |
----------------------------------
3      |   saws     |  OVERDUE   |     <---------- this row will become yellow This row only.
----------------------------------
```

I want to get column lname ,how to do that? Can anyone give some example coding?

**This is my code:**

```
  If gridalarmnotice(20, gridalarmnotice.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value.ToString = "OVERDUE" Then
      gridalarmnotice.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow  
  End If
```

I want to change backgroundcolor if the column and current cell is equal to OVERDUE.

Comment: You want to get last name column, but you want to make sure the column and the cell equals overdue; this makes no sense please elaborate.

Comment: Example for the column lname, if there is "overdue" the whole row of the current cell will be yellow not all the table but only the current cell.

Comment: So last name holds overdue? Also you said the whole row of the current cell will be yellow are you sure. Before you mentioned just that cell...

Comment: Yup!, if the current column cell contains "OVERDUE".

Comment: Ok, now that I understand what you need, give me a little.

Comment: Try to look again my proposal code, and my scenario. For example my lname is in the cell index 20, If in the COLUMN lname has a OVERDUE, the WHOLE ROW of the current cell background will become yellow, and the other row is still normal background.

Comment: wrong it maybe in many different rows ...

Comment: yes it can be in defferent rows. All I want is to change the back color of row that has containing OVERDUE.

Comment: Correct, almost got it for you, had to boot up the machine.

Comment: Answer submitted, let me know how it works out for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work just great for you.

Put this method in your class wherever you want... Then call it. . For ex: a button click event...

```
 Private Sub HighlightRows()
    'Loop through the rows, if the current rows cell equals "OVERDUE"
    'change the rows color to yellow
    For i As Integer = 0 To gridalarmnotice.Rows.Count - 1
        If gridalarmnotice.Rows(i).Cells("lname").Value.Equals("OVERDUE") Then
            'Then color the whole row, each cell specifically
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In gridalarmnotice.Rows(i).Cells
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Next
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

P.S. Here's my screenshot of my test.

[image]